# React app using github pages not updating

Tags: reactjs, git, github-pages

I've deployed a react app to GitHub pages successfully and want to commit the changes for my actual app so they can appear on the Github pages link. To do this I copied all my code to the main branch but when I run npm run deploy the link still displays the react app starter thing as if it's not listening to the main branch. Here is a link to my repo below. Any help is greatly appreciated.

https://github.com/devghai/myapp

Comment: the package.json in your repo does not contain a deploy script. So only guessing here. Did you build before deploying?

Comment: @ian But does it (gh-pages) even allow to run the npm scripts?

Comment: @GermaVinsmoke gh-pages as far as i understand it. Takes the content of the gh-pages branch and static hosts them. That's why you have to build your react app and then push the build folder to gh-pages branch. Deploy would for me only imply the second step witch pushes the old build. That is why I wanted to see the deploy script.

Comment: @ian Thank you for the help! on terminal I run npm run build and then npm run deploy and my website still displays the starter react webpage. How can I push the build folder to gh-pages so it static hosts them?